# Rerun sucessful oozie jobs

Tags: scheduled-tasks, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

Is there a way to fully rerun successful oozie jobs. Let assume that we schedule creation a table and we want to rebuild it on demand - is there easy way to do it in oozie?

I try oozie -rerun command but if every action is successful it will not perform any results. It just checked that everything is successful and finish the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerun with oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes set to false (it is true by default).

Example:

`oozie job -rerun 0000092-141219003455004-oozie-oozi-W -config job.properties -Doozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=false`

From *Apache Oozie* by Mohammad Kamrul Islam and Aravind Srinivasan

> By default, workflow reruns start executing from the failed nodes in the prior run.... The property oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes can be set to false to tell Oozie that the entire workflow needs to be rerun.

Answer (score 0):

If your job ran successfully and you want to rerun on demand you will have to find out the action number first by running this command:  `oozie job -info xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-C`
and once you have the action number run this: `oozie job -rerun xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-C -action xx`
and you should be good then